# How can I set the baseURL for expect in playwright?

Tags: javascript, playwright, playwright-test

In my Playwright tests, I set the [base-url](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testoptions#test-options-base-url) according to the docs:

```
const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
  projects: [
    {
      name: 'Safari MacBook Air',
      use: {
        browserName: 'webkit',
        viewport: {
          width: 2560,
          height: 1620,
        },
        contextOptions: {
          ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
        },
      },
    },
  ],
  use: {
    baseURL: process.env.PLATFORMSH_URL,
    headless: false,
    locale: 'ja-JP',

    // Debugging artifacts.
    screenshot: 'on',
    trace: 'on',
    video: 'on',
  },
};
export default config;
```

This is working for `goto`:

```
await this.page.goto('/myDirectory');
```

However, it fails for `expect`:

```
  expect(page.url()).toBe('/myPage');
```

The error is:

> ```
> Expected: "/myPage"
> Received: "https://www.example.com/myPage"
> ```

How can I use `expect` with `baseURL`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try using this assertion instead:
For example, having configured Playwright homepage as our baseUrl

```
   {
     name: 'webkit',
     use: {
       ...devices['Desktop Safari'],
       baseURL: 'https://playwright.dev/'
     },
   },
```

Then:

```
test('baseUrl', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('/docs/intro');
  await expect(page).toHaveURL('/docs/intro');
});
```

If you'd like to continue using this format:

```
  expect(page.url()).toBe('/myPage');
```

Then you need to change the assertion, because the url you're at is not equal to your directory. You can assert the url you're at contains the aforementioned directory, instead:

```
  expect(page.url()).toContain('/myPage');
```

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong in your code except the last line.
`page.url()` will give you the whole URL address on wich your
driver (browser,whathever) currently is, and `expect(something)toBe(thing)` is like equals, and it will fail in your case.

You can assert in several ways like:

await expect(page.url().includes(partOfUrl)).toBeTruthy();

Answer (score 1):

In the end I just wrapped it in my own utility function:

```
const pwaBaseUrl = process.env.NOSLASH_URL;

export const assertPath = async (page: Page, path: string) => {
  expect(page.url()).toBe(`${pwaBaseUrl}/${path}`);
};
```

This guarantees that I am on the exact path.  Perhaps this isn't generally necessary, but coming from Behat testing on PHP, this is what I'm used to.